# How to apply a class to a specific label in a row based on truthy value

Tags: vuejs3

I'm new to Vue 3. I have a table with rows. See screenshot below. Each row has a checkbox and a label in it. All I want to do is upon **initial** loading of the page view, have the correct class apply to the label depending on whether the child.status of that row is true-thy or not. Child status true is present. False = absent. Problem: when I initially load the page view **all** the labels are green regardless whether the child.status false or true.

Currently the Vue 3 code I have got so far works great, except for initial load.  If I check the checkbox, I get the data I need and the label gets its green background. If I uncheck a checkbox, the green class disappears. Check it again and the green background reappears - Great. All's well except for initial page load where all the labels are green.

To help you understand I included a screenshot. You will notice behind each label there is a 1 or 0 to indicate whether it is truthy are not. You will see that even the false ones are green.

```html
<template>
    <div class="container">

        <h5 class="heading ml-4">Children Absent / Present</h5>

        <div class="border_charts">
            <table class="table ">
                <thead>
                <tr class="col-4">
                    <th class="tableHeading col-4">First Name</th>
                    <th class="tableHeading col-4">Last Name</th>
                    <th class="tableHeading col-4 ">Absent / Present</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr v-for="child in Children" :key="child.child_id">
                    <td class="col-4"><a :href="'/getchild/'+ child.child_id">{{child.childFirstName}}</a></td>
                    <td class="col-4"> {{child.childLastName}}</td>
                    <td class="col-4">
                        <div class="form-check form-switch" >
                            <input
                                type="checkbox"
                                class="form-check-input"
                                role="switch"
                                :id="child.child_id"
                                v-model="child.status"
                                :true-value="1"
                                :false-value="0"
                                @change="updateChild(child)"
                            >
                        
                            <label
                                class="form-check-label"
                                v-bind:for="child.child_id "
                                :class="{present:child.status}"
                                :true-value="1"
                                :false-value="0"
                            >  {{ child.status ? absentPresent : absentPresent }}
                            </label>

                            {{child.status}}

                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

    props: {
        Children:{
            Children:Array
         },
    },

    data() {
        return {
            active:false,
            inputClass: 'present',
            absentPresent:'Absent/Present'
        }
    },

    methods:{
        updateChild(child){
            this.changedChild = child;
            console.log( this.changedChild);
            this.inputClass = 'present'
            this.active = ! this.active
        },
    },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
 .present{
     background-color: #5ba17a;
     border-radius:0.25rem;
     width:auto;
     color:white;
     text-align: center;
     margin: 2px;
     padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
 }

 .absent{
     width:auto;
     color:darkblue;
     text-align: center;}

</style>
```

[image: Screen Shot of Labels]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that `child.status` is initially loaded as string, so it is `'0'` instead of `0`, and as with any non-empty string, `Boolean('0')` is true.

Check if you need to convert the values to numbers after loading, or if you can change the data source to send you numbers instead of strings.

Comment: You are a freaking rockstar! Thank you! That worked. All I did  was change the DB table to int from varchar and BINGO. I had been sweating over this for hours!! I have been using raw JS for 10 years. Being a Vue Newb is a pain.